# Preventing Auto-Reset of Zoom/Pan in ApexCharts on Series Update

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm working with ApexCharts to display live data fetched initially from an InfluxDB, which is then continuously updated via WebSocket messages. Each incoming message triggers an update to the chart's series with updateSeries().

However, I've encountered a challenge: whenever updateSeries() is called to append new data points, the chart automatically resets to its default zoom and pan settings. This automatic "homing" behavior prevents users from analyzing past data, as the view resets before they can thoroughly examine the zoomed or panned areas.

Question: Is there a way to append new data points to the chart without triggering the view to reset to the default zoom and pan settings? I'd like the current view (zoom level and pan position) to remain unchanged when new data is added.

I've simplified the problem in the following example. Please attempt to zoom out and pan slightly to observe the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Refreshing Apex Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h5 class="card-title" id="chartTitle">Refreshing Apex Chart | <span id="lastUpdate">Pending</span></h5>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

<script>

// Function to generate initial data points
function generateInitialData() {
    const data = [];
    const now = new Date();

    for (let i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        const time = new Date(now.getTime() - i * 1000).getTime();
        const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // Generate a random value
        data.push([time, value]);
    }
    return data;
}

// Initialize the chart data with 10 data points
let series = [{
    name: 'Sample Data Series',
    data: generateInitialData()
}];

// Function to add new data
function addData() {
    const newTime = new Date().getTime();
    const newValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // Generate a random value
    series[0].data.push([newTime, newValue]);

    // Update the chart
    chart.updateSeries(series);

    // Update the last update time
    document.getElementById('lastUpdate').textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('de-DE');
}

// Initialize the chart
let options = {
    series: series,
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'area',
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 2,
        curve: 'smooth',
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();

// Update data every second
setInterval(addData, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```